# UITextView userinteraction not working

Tags: ios

I have an `UImageView` and on that I have a `UITextView` when I take this `UImageView` for cropping and return back my keyboard is not showing but I can change my text color and text size and I also can not move my `UITextView` through `panGesture`. I have done image rendering for adding `UITextView` to the `UImageView` through following code:

```
[passingImageView addSubview:textView];
[canvas addSubview:passingImageView];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(canvas.bounds.size);
[canvas.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return resultingImage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `UIImageView` usually don't have `userInteractionEnabled` `TRUE` from default. Just do

```
passingImageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

It should work.

Cheers.

Comment: @Bruce : How come **+1 for your answer**, if you have 1 reputation .anyhow, if it answers your question, then accept the answer .

Comment: @Bruce Yup sure, in SO, if you have posted a question, and any answer that solves your problem, you should accept that an answer to help others, there is a unselected right sign along with answer, you can select it.